# Regular Expression to remove selective string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

Looking to remove particular string coming in between json string:

**For Example my Json string is :**

```
{"tableName":"avzConf","rows":[{"Comp":"mster","Conf": "[{\"name\": \"state\", \"dispN\": \"c_d_test\", \"\": {\"updated_at\": \"2020-09-16T06:33:07.684504Z\", \"updated_by\": \"Abc_xyz<abc_xyz@uuvvww.com>\"}}, {\"name\": \"stClu\", \"dNme\": \"tab(s) Updatedd\", \"\": {\"updated_at\": \"2020-09-21T10:17:48.307874Z\", \"updated_by\": \"Def Ghi<def_ghi@uuvvww.com>\"}}
}]
}
```

**want to remove:** `\"\": {\"updated_at\": \"2020-09-16T06:33:07.684504Z\", \"updated_by\": \"Abc_xyz<abc_xyz@uuvvww.com>\"}`

**Expected output :**

```
{"tableName":"avzConf","rows":[{"Comp":"mster","Conf": "[{\"name\": \"state\", \"dispN\": \"c_d_test\"}, {\"name\": \"stClu\", \"dNme\": \"tab(s) Updatedd\"}
}]
}
```

**I tried with** `( \\"\\": {\\"updated_\w+)(.*)(>\\")`

**used in my code:**

```
import re

line = re.sub(r"updated_\w+(.*)(.com>)", '', json_str)
```

But it's also selecting the between lines as there is 2 occurrences of "": {"updated_at\ and "updated_by"

And leaving special char "": {""}

How can I completely remove `\"\": {\"updated_at\": \"2020-09-16T06:33:07.684504Z\", \"updated_by\": \"Abc_xyz<abc_xyz@uuvvww.com>\"}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python json string I'm able to remove those unwanted fields as below:
this has completely removed the unwanted empty key and replace the same with }, to complete the json perfectly.

```
regex as \,\s\\\"\\\":\s\{\\\"updated_at[^{]+\}[^\]]

json_str = str({"tableName":"avzConf","rows":[{"Comp":"mster","Conf": "[{"name": "state", "dispN": "c_d_test", "": {"updated_at": "2020-09-16T06:33:07.684504Z", "updated_by": "Abc_xyzabc_xyz@uuvvww.com"}}, {"name": "stClu", "dNme": "tab(s) Updatedd", "": {"updated_at": "2020-09-21T10:17:48.307874Z", "updated_by": "Def Ghidef_ghi@uuvvww.com"}} }] })

import re
line = re.sub(r"\,\s\\\"\\\":\s\{\\\"updated_at[^{]+\}",'},', json_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\{\"updated_at[^{]+\}
```

This matches from the relevant opening `{` to the relevant closing `}`by allowing any character except `{` to occur once or more times in-between

Comment: Thanks Chris for the quick help. I took idea from your regex and modified it bit according my requirement. this mainly worked for me \s\\\"\\\":\s\{\\\"updated_at[^{]+\}[^\]]